# Unix: How to kill a list of processes (PID) based on the lsof command?

Tags: unix, kill, lsof

I would like to kill a list of PID that correlates to a process in a tcsh shell. I ran the following command:

```
> losf <file> | awk '{print($2)"'
```

The command will show a list of PIDs.

> pid1
>
> pid2
>
> ...

I then ran the following command to kill those PIDs.

```
> kill -9 `lsof <file> | awk'{print($2)}'`
```

When the `kill` command is executed, the terminal just somehow hanged without killing any PID. I then had to revert to killing those PID one by one.

Therefore, is there a way to do what I intended to do as illustrated above? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xargs` is a standard utility for performing action on each given line read from standard input. You could use it like this:

```
> lsof <file> | awk '{print($2)}' | xargs -I '{}' kill {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution, this one liner is working for me and it is what I have been searching for. I edited your answer to the following as the original answer has a syntax error.

`Original: awk 'print {$2}'`
`Edited: awk '{print($2)}'`

Comment: @user3531168 Somehow I completely missed your edit, I've accepted it now. Thanks and sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try
`for i in (lsof <file>); echo "pkill"$i`
or you could also try sometihng like
`lsof <file> > pkill` though I'm not holding any hope that would work..

Comment: Thank you for this but I couldn't try this out as I'm using a tcsh shell that doesn't have "for" command. I've managed to used foreach command instead.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve that using the following foreach method:

```
> foreach id (`lsof <file> | awk '{print($2)"'`)
foreach? kill -9 $id
foreach? end
```

I'm not sure whether is there a better way to do this without writing a script for such usage.

Answer (score 0):

Have you come across the `fuser` command.
The option -k will kill all processes with the named file/files open.

```
fuser -k -TERM /home/rolf/fs3/fs3.db /home/rolf/fs2.db
/home/rolf/fs3/fs3.db:  4026  4058
/home/rolf/fs2.db:   3996
```

by default KILL is sent but you can change that to TERM for example with the `-SIGNAL` option